# Can't access Workgroup Computer

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, authentication, workgroup

This is a weird one. Essentially I have a standard Workgroup at home, several PC's, and on each machine, the Administrator account unlocked in lusrmgr.msc. Password set the same for each PC so I can do push installs for Backup Exec and AVG etc.

One machine however, I just can't login to. I can't even access shares using either the administrator account or the actual users account who shared the files (And I am putting the correct Computer_Name\Username!).

It just errors like you are using the wrong credentials. Any ideas? I have tried creating other user accounts, standard user and administrator accounts, if I turn off password protected sharing it's fine for user shares, but I still can't push install using the credentials.

Comment: Are all the computers running Windows 7? What firewall? Can you connect using `NET USE`?

Comment: All Windows 7, all on Windows Firewall. Sorry what do you mean connect via NET USE/

Comment: I have just looked into Syntax of NET USE and tried accessing a share and mapping it to a drive - received error 5, access denied.

Comment: Are they all in the same workgroup? Right-click on Computer, click `Properties`. Click on `Advanced System Settings`->`Computer Name`. Can the computer you can't connect to connect with another machine?

Comment: All in same Workgroup, WORKGROUP, and no, no other machines can seem to authenticate to this one PC

Comment: What I mean is, with Machine B not connectible, can Machine B connect to Machine A's shares?

Comment: Ah, Sorry I misunderstood. Yes, it can

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3943/discussion-between-luke-and-thed)